# Elasticsearch: Multiply each nested element plus aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's imagine an index composed of 2 documents like this one:

```
doc1 = {
       "x":1,
       "y":[{brand:b1, value:1},
            {brand:b2, value:2}]
       },

doc2 = {
       "x":2,
       "y":[{brand:b1, value:0},
            {brand:b2, value:3}]
       }
```

Is it possible to multiply each values of y by x for each document and then do sum aggregation based on brand term to get this result:

```
b1: 1
b2: 8
```

If not, could it be done with any other mapping types ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly custom use-case so I don't think there's some sort of a pre-optimized mapping for it.

What I would suggest is the following:

Set up an index w/ `y` being `nested`:

```
PUT xy/
{"mappings":{"properties":{"y":{"type":"nested"}}}}
```

Ingest the docs from your example:

```
POST xy/_doc
{"x":1,"y":[{"brand":"b1","value":1},{"brand":"b2","value":2}]}

POST xy/_doc
{"x":2,"y":[{"brand":"b1","value":0},{"brand":"b2","value":3}]}
```

Use a [`scripted_metric`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation to compute the products and add them up in a shared `HashMap`:

```
GET xy/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "multiply_and_add": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.by_brands = [:]",
        "map_script": """
          def x = params._source['x'];
          for (def brand_pair : params._source['y']) {
            def brand = brand_pair['brand'];
            def product = x * brand_pair['value'];
            if (state.by_brands.containsKey(brand)) {
              state.by_brands[brand] += product;
            } else {
              state.by_brands[brand] = product;
            }
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": "return state",
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which would yield something along the lines of

```
{
  ... 
  "aggregations":{
    "multiply_and_add":{
      "value":[
        {
          "by_brands":{   <----
            "b2":8,            
            "b1":1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE

The `combine_script` could look like this:

```
def combined_states = [:];
for (def state : states) {
  for (def brand_pair : state['by_brands'].entrySet()) {
    def key = brand_pair.getKey();
    def value = brand_pair.getValue();
    
    if (combined_states.containsKey(key)) {
      combined_states[key] += (float)value;
      break;
    } 
    
    combined_states[key] = (float)value
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm getting this result (using 6.8 version):


{'took': 3,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': 2, 'max_score': 0.0, 'hits': []},
 'aggregations': {'multiply_and_add': {'value': [{'by_brands': {}},
    {'by_brands': {'b2': 6, 'b1': 0}},
    {'by_brands': {'b2': 2, 'b1': 1}},
    {'by_brands': {}},
    {'by_brands': {}}]}}}


How can I specify sum of brands in the "reduce_scripts" ? To finally get something like: 
"b2":8,            
"b1":1

Comment: Are you sure you've set up your `y` mapping as `nested`?

Comment: Would it be possible to compute sum in reduce_script ?

Comment: Yes, adding an example to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now. I just put the combined script in "reduce_script" tag.
I will try to run this aggregation on a huge index, with over 100 thousands of documents to test performance.

Thanks again !